# If one of the sequences in an infinite series is divergent, then does it imply the series is divergent?

Tags: calculus

Suppose an infinite series can be expressed as the infinite series of two sequences and one of which is divergent, then does it imply that the series is divergent?

Comment: This is not clear.  $1-\frac 12+\frac 13-\frac 14+\cdots $ converges but $1+\frac 13+\frac 15+\cdots$ diverges.  Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

$$1 = \sum_{n\ge 1} \left(\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}\right) = \sum_{n\ge 1}\left( \dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

Comment: Since the harmonic series is divergent can I conclude the series is divergent without checking for the other sequence?

Comment: No. For instance $\sum \frac 1n$ is divergent but $\sum(\frac 1n - \frac 1n) = \sum 0 = 0$ is convergent.

Comment: I think the example wanted to show you the opposite... $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ is convergent (compare it with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$) and since $\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$, the second series is also convergent. With regards to this type of series, you may want to lookup "telescopic" or "Mengoli" series.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If the series $\sum_{n \geq \infty} a_{n}$ converges, then the sequence $(a_{n})_{n \geq \infty}$ converges to zero, hence so does its every subsequence.